# How can I randomise a song when one has finished?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a radio that is powered by an AI. At the moment, when you refresh the page it will randomly play a song but I want to make it so it will play another random song when the other one is finished. How can I do that? This is my current code:

```js
    let SongsLength = 104
    let SongsPlayed = 0
    let songToPlay = Math.floor(Math.random(1, SongsLength) * SongsLength + 1)
    document.getElementById("SongsChoose").innerHTML = `<source src="./Songs/1 (${songToPlay}).mp3" type="audio/mpeg">`
    SongsPlayed = SongsPlayed + 1
    if(SongsPlayed === 5) {
        SongsPlayed = 0
    }
```

Comment: listen for the ended event?

Comment: how do I fetch the ended event?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio